# Rails Timestamps UTC vs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm getting a failing rpsec test and it seems like it's a difference between the system clock and how Rails evaluates the time.

```

```
expected: 2015-01-01 15:00:00.000000000 -0800
got: 2015-01-01 15:00:00.000000000 +0000

(compared using ==)

Diff:
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-2015-01-01 15:00:00 -0800
+2015-01-01 15:00:00 UTC
```

```

For some reason `Time.parse('01/01/2015 3:00pm')` coerces the string into the timezone on the system clock.  But the code is under test is outputting in UTC.

Does anyone know why or where this happens?

Comment: Check in your config.rb if there's a timezone set. Could be why you're getting -0800

Comment: You might also prefer `Time.zone.parse`

Comment: Config/application.rb sets a timezone, but it's a different one than either the expected timezone in the spec or what the code actually generates.

Comment: Time.zone.parse did the trick!.  Thanks @JimVanFleet!

Comment: You need to show us the relevant test code.

Comment: @BenDowney Added the full explanation as a real answer if you care to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the behavior of `Time.parse`.  Replacing that call with `Time.zone.parse` allows an [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html)

Though the particulars of [the implementation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) may vary, you can get the sense of the design goals of `Time.parse` from this documentation:

> Since there are numerous conflicts among locally defined time zone abbreviations all over the world, this method is not intended to understand all of them.

GMT is considered the default time, and matches the output you report above.  Replacing it with an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` allows Rails configuration to amend that default expectation.